# How to remove " from json nested value

Tags: javascript, json

How do I remove special char " in data and origin value below?

**EDIT:**
I have added comma after blue before origin, the actual issue was how to make "[]" to [] after origin.

I want from this:

```
{ 
  "data" : "[{
    "color": "blue",
    "origin": "[{"state" : "USA"}, {"state" : "AFRICA"}]"
  }]"
}
```

To This:

```
{ 
  "data" : [{
    "color": "blue",
    "origin": [{"state" : "USA"}, {"state" : "AFRICA"}]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Is it really broken JSON that looks like this `"origin": "[{"state" : "USA"}, {"state" : "AFRICA"}]"` or are the `"` at the `origin` part escaped and it actually looks that way: `"origin": "[{\"state" : \"USA\"}, {\"state\" : \"AFRICA\"}]"`?

Comment: I just saw that the first quote already starts at `"data" : "[{`, so there have to be even more ```\``` to make everything valid.

Comment: There is a comma missing after blue and before origin. So there are many problems with the original json.

Comment: As previous comment says, original object that you are attempting to transform is not a valid javascript object. Trying to use that anywhere will cause a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`. In this object `"data"` is interpreted as the object key, and "[{
    " gets interpreted as the value. Then you just hit a syntax error with color and all the rest. Need to use escapes.

Comment: I have added comma after blue before origin, the actual issue was to make "[]" to [] after origin.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const strArr = "[{\"foo\": \"bar\"}]";
const arr = JSON.parse(strArr);
console.log(arr);
```

if that objects name is say "obj" you can do:

```js
obj.data = JSON.parse(obj.data);
```

this will convert a valid json string into an array

Edit:
if you are just trying to make origin an array instead of a string (assuming valid json) it is probably best you just JSON parse the whole thing then set origin to JSON.parse(origin)

```js
let data = "[{\"color\": \"blue\", \"origin\": \"[{\\\"state\\\": \\\"USA\\\"},{\\\"state\\\": \\\"AFRICA\\\"}]\"}]";

let obj = {
  data: data
};

let objData = JSON.parse(obj.data);
objData[0].origin = JSON.parse(objData[0].origin);
console.log(objData);
```

Comment: Have you tried that with OP's example?

Comment: well he has invalid looking json... that is a whole different problem ha

Comment: Yeah that was my observation, your answer assumes the JSON is actually valid. Which OP's isn't.

Comment: How does this fix OP's broken JSON? It doesn't answer the question

Comment: I have added comma after blue before origin, the actual issue was to make "[]" to [] after origin.

Comment: @ssDev are you not including the escape characters in your json string? like that is the exact string you are trying to deserialize? Because it won't work due to the unescaped double quotes within double quotes

Comment: @Undo ..I was kind of assuming the actual json string would be valid and that the posted one wasn't correct, probably not the best assumption but escape characters in json is a whole different question and I would need to know where they are getting the json from, if it can be changed to be valid and a bunch of other stuff that would probably be hard to get into without a question pertaining specifically to that